# Does the Laplacian commute with the Heat semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f \in L^p(D)$, with $1 \leq p\leq \infty$. We say that $f$ admit a weak $L^p$-Laplacian if there exists a function $g\in L^p(D)$ such that for all functions $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(D)$ we have $$\int_D f\Delta \phi dx = \int_D g\phi dx.$$
We can define the weak $L^p$-Laplacian on D with domain : $$D(\Delta_{p,D}):=\{f\in L^p(D) : \text{f admits a weak }L^p\text{-Laplacian on D} \}.$$

In the next part we will denote the weak Laplacian using $\Delta$ or $\Delta_p$.

For every $t>0$ we define the heat kernel
$$K_t(x):=(4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}.$$

For $1\leq p < \infty$, $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t\geq0$ we define the heat semigroup on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the family $H :=\{H(t)\}_{t\geq0}$ where $H(t)$ satisfy
$$H(t)f(x) = K_t*f(x), \ f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^d), x\in \mathbb{R}^d,$$ when $t>0$ and $$H(t) = I$$ when $t=0$.

For $f\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, I have

$$H(t)f-f = K_t*f-f =  \int_0^t \frac{d}{ds}(K_s*f)ds= \int_0^t (\Delta K_s)*fds= \int_0^t \Delta H(s)fds.$$

In order to prove that this is true for $f\in D(\Delta_p)$, It seems that I need $H(s)\Delta f = \Delta H(s) f$. Is that true and how can I show such a result ?

Comment: On sufficiently nice domains $\Omega$ we have the integration by parts formula from which it follows that $\int_\Omega \Delta f g \,\text{d}x = \int_\Omega f\Delta g \,\text{d}x$ for all $f,g\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: @stange Hello, thanks but here we integrate over $s$. Then, $H(s)$ is an operator, we can show that $\Delta H(s) f = \Delta (K_s *f)=( \Delta K_s) *f $, but I don't think we can apply the integration by part here

Comment: If $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $\Delta(K_s\ast f) = \Delta K_s\ast f = K_s\ast\Delta f$, which should be your desired equality.

Comment: Hello @stange, indeed, in the case of $f \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ that is true, but in our case we have $f \in \Delta_p$